# LinkedList/Stack/Queue - Help with Dequeuing

Tags: c++, queue, linked-list, stack

I had to write a linked list, then turn it into a dynamic Stack, then turn that into a dynamic Queue. Well everything seems to work except the "dequeuing", right as the programs about to finish, it gives me an error: "An unhandled win32 exception occured in LinkedList_Stack_BNS11.exe [4972].".

I'm only assuming it's the dequeuing, because as I step through and/or run the program, it runs smoothly up till that part, so maybe I sent one of the pointers wrong or something?

**Output:**

Enquing 5 items....
// Finsihes

The values in the queue were (Dequeuing):

0

1

2

// Correct number in que but...

//Program gives that error right here. When it should finish and close.

If I included too much code let me know and I'll chop it down to just the "Dequeuing" (Which is in the very middle of all the stuff below)

Thanks in advance for the help!! I'm just not seeing what I did wrong. Thinking it maybe has something to do with where "head" is pointing? Idk.

**Header File:**

```
class NumberList
{
private:
    //
    struct ListNode
    {
        int value;  // Value in this node
        struct ListNode *next; // Pointer to the next node
    };

    ListNode *head; // List head pointer
    ListNode *rear;

public:
    //Constructor
    NumberList()
    { head = NULL; rear = NULL; }

    //Destructor
    ~NumberList();

    //Stack operations
    bool isEmpty();

    //Queue operations
    void enqueue(int);
    void dequeue(int &);
};
#endif
```

**List_Stack_Queue.cpp:**

```
bool NumberList::isEmpty()
{
    bool status;

    if(!head)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;

    return status;
}

     void NumberList::enqueue(int num)
    {
        ListNode *newNode; // Point to a new node

        // Allocate a new node and store num there.
        newNode = new ListNode;
        newNode->value = num;

        //If there are no nodes in the list
        // make newNode the first node.
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            head = newNode;
            rear = head;
            //newNode->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            rear->next = newNode;
            rear = rear->next;
            //newNode->next = head;
            //head = newNode;
        }
    }

    void NumberList::dequeue(int &num)
    {
        ListNode *temp;

        if(isEmpty())
            cout << "The queue is empty.\n";
        else
        {
            num = head->value;
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
```

**MAIN:**

```
const int MAX_VALUES = 3;

// Create a DynIntQueue object.
NumberList iQueue;

// Enqueue a series of numbers.
cout << "Enqueuing " << MAX_VALUES << " items...\n";
for (int x = 0; x < MAX_VALUES; x++)
    iQueue.enqueue(x);

cout << endl;

//Dequeue and retrieve all numbers in the queue
cout << "The values in the queue were (Dequeuing):\n";
while(!iQueue.isEmpty())
{
    int value;
    iQueue.dequeue(value);
    cout << value << endl;
} 
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last nodes's next element should be set to **NULL** in a linked list. So,

```
void NumberList::enqueue(int num)
{
    // ...
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        head = newNode;
        head->next = NULL;
        rear = head;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = newNode;
        rear = rear->next;
        rear->next = NULL;     // Pointing the next node element to null.
    }
}
```

To, me it seems some thing is wrong with `Numberlist::isEmpty();` member function. How you are deciding whether the list is empty or not ? Show the definition of it.

Comment: thanks!! That code of yours did it, works now with no errors! :) Posted up the Numberlist::isEmpty() in the cpp file (At the top).
Saved me a couple points on my assignment thanks again :).
Question: I'm trying to tempaltize it now, so instead of posting a new question, should I just edit this question?